# kubernetes API object created by a deployement creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, amazon-eks

I try to see all the kubernetes object used to create a deployment. How to see theses objects created when `kubectl run mydep --image=busybox` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while existing answers provide an answer, its best if you understand what happens, so you can have an idea how to solve such issues. take a look here: https://github.com/jamiehannaford/what-happens-when-k8s. its quite a read, but worth it.

Answer (score 3):

After running `kubectl run mydep --image=busybox` , Existing objects can be viewed in a ready to use YAML output using below command:

```
  kubectl get deployments mydep --export -o yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use kubectl to see all the deployments created using `kubectl run` or `kubectl create`.

I ran your command on my cluster and I can see following using kubectl:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-91 centos]# kubectl run mydep --image=busybox
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/mydep created

[root@ip-10-0-1-91 centos]# kubectl get deployments
NAME             DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
mydep            1         1         1            0           17s

[root@ip-10-0-1-91 centos]# kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
mydep-6d67498bcf-24zh2            0/1     Completed   2          28s
```